# Paginating long text in Rails w/ MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination

What's the current best practice for paginating long text, for instance, splitting a long article into multiple pages?

The two options as I can think of:

- store the string in a longtext column, slice it to an array and paginate over that. However, I'm worried about memory usage and doing too much processing on the page load.
- slice up the text and store it in a page model (Article has_many :pages). Should work fine, but we'd lose the flexibility of changing the page length.

What's the best approach? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: how long is the text typically?

Comment: Initially it will need to account for at least 20000 words/120000 characters, though it will likely be a bit higher than that from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to go with the first approach, and put the sliced results in a cache (like memcached), so that you keep the flexibility of changing page lengths without having to slice the page every time you serve it.

Answer (score 0):

If the text is usually less than 10MB, it's perfectly reasonable to split the text in the action. The memory overhead of Rails is so much larger than that, so you shouldn't be concerned.

However, if the text is usually more than 10MB, you should select the substring directly from your datastore. For example, if you're using MySQL and ActiveRecord, you could do something like this:

```
# assuming fields `id`, and `body`
class Article < ActiveRecord
  def self.find_page(id, page_number, page_size = 10_000)
    page_number = page_number.to_i
    page_size = page_size.to_i
    pos = page_size * (page_number - 1)
    # http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring
    find(id, :select => "id, SUBSTRING(body, #{pos}, #{page_size}) AS body")
  end
end
```

(10MB is, of course, an arbitrary number. Pick one that suits you)